# SOQL for a lookup relation

Tags: soql

I have a custom object Called 'Interest_Level__c'. From contact I have a lookup to Interest_level__c object with relationship name 'Contacts' and Field 'Interested__c'. Now I'm trying to get the 'Name' of Interest_Level__c record.

Here is my query:

```
select Id, Name, Contacts__r.Name from Contact
```

Comment: So `Interested__c` is the name of the field on your `Contact` object?

Comment: yes its the field on contact

Answer (score 3):

```
select Id, Name, Interested__r.Name from Contact
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    SELECT Id, Name, (Select Name from Contacts__r) FROM Interest_Level__c
```

Comment: I want to query from Contact

Answer (score 0):

when you want to use related lookup field (Interested__c) on any object (contact) then you have to use "Interested__c" field only it gives you only Id of related record (Interested__c).

When you want more information from lookup field like Name and other fields then we have to use lookup relationship object which is "Interested__r".
This object will contains all information related to your lookup record.

It will provide name for related lookup record :
select Id, Name, Interested__r.Name from Contact

Relationship type Name "Contacts" will be used only when you have to get all  Interest_Level__c record related to contact.

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the id of Interested record:

```
select Id, Name, Interested__c from Contact
```

This give you the Name:

```
select Id,Interested__r.Name from Contact
```

You need to use `__r` relationship when you are accessing the fields of a lookup field.